# Execute script after period of inactivity

Tags: scripting, keyboard, mouse

I'm looking for a way to execute certain script after period of inactivity and after completion of that period. By 'inactivity' I mean lack of mouse and keyboard events. E.g. I want:

1. execute first script after X min. of inactivity;
2. execute second script when that period is interrupted by mouse or keyboard.

It will be best if that method will not be tied to the X-system and also will work in terminal (when X is not started).

Comment: Under which unix variant?

Comment: @Gilles, Linux. Arch Linux, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a little C magic (any other programming language supporting the needed functions will be fine, too).  What you'll have to do is:

- open all `input` event devices (everything matching `/dev/input/event[0-9]*`)
- have `select(2)` called on those devices, waiting for input, with an appropriate timeout (your idle period)

  - on timeout: nothing happened: start your program
  - if input becomes ready: something happened: kill your program, if running
- `read(2)` input from all devices, so the next `select(2)` call won't return immediately

A quick example in C would look like this:

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *fds, ret, i;
    glob_t glob_result;

    /* find all devices matching /dev/input/event[0-9]* */
    ret = glob("/dev/input/event[0-9]*", GLOB_ERR|GLOB_NOSORT|GLOB_NOESCAPE, NULL, &glob_result);
    if (ret)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "glob");

    /* allocate array for opened file descriptors */
    fds = malloc(sizeof(*fds) * (glob_result.gl_pathc+1));
    if (fds == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "malloc");

    /* open devices */
    for (i = 0; i < glob_result.gl_pathc; i++) {
        fds[i] = open(glob_result.gl_pathv[i], O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
        if (fds[i] == -1)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "open `%s'", glob_result.gl_pathv[i]);
    }

    fds[i] = -1; /* end of array */

    for (;;) {
        char buf[512];
        struct timeval timeout;
        fd_set readfds;
        int nfds = -1;

        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        /* select(2) might alter the fdset, thus freshly set it
           on every iteration */
        for (i = 0; fds[i] != -1; i++) {
            FD_SET(fds[i], &readfds);
            nfds = fds[i] >= nfds ? fds[i] + 1 : nfds;

            /* read everything what's available on this fd */
            while ((ret = read(fds[i], buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
                continue; /* read away input */
            if (ret == -1 && errno != EAGAIN)
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "read");
        }

        /* same for timeout, 5 seconds here */
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;    /* FIXME */
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        ret = select(nfds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (ret == -1)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "select");
        if (ret == 0)
            printf("Timeout: start first script\n");
        } else {
            printf("No timeout: start second script\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This example would wait for input indefinitely.  If after 5 seconds no input is received, it would print "Timeout: …", if input is received "No timeout: …"

For further reading (you want to execute and kill processes, though), see `fork(2)`, `exec(2)` and `kill(2)` respectively.  As mentioned earlier, every language allowing to run `select(2)` on files would suffice, so you could also do is in Python or Ruby or something alike.

**Note:**  This is just an example, there would be additional things to be taken care of.  For example, this prints "Timeout" *every* 5 seconds, not just only once until input is received, similarly "No timeout" comes on *every* key-stroke/mouse-movement.

Also, this would need to be run as `root`, since the `input` event devices aren't readable by anybody for obvious reasons.

Comment: This is awesome. I searched around and all I could found were solutions based on X or polling some other tool. I do not always run X on my machine. I may even not be logged in. Of course this has to be `sudo`ed but that's expected. Thanks, I hope to give it a try.

Comment: OK well it does not compile, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C application that I found which you can compile.

```
$ more xidle.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>

/* Report amount of X server idle time. */
/* Build with- */
/* cc xidle.c -o xidle -lX11 -lXext -lXss */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display *display;
    int event_base, error_base;
    XScreenSaverInfo info;
    float seconds;

    display = XOpenDisplay("");

    if (XScreenSaverQueryExtension(display, &event_base, &error_base)) {
    XScreenSaverQueryInfo(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), &info);

    seconds = (float)info.idle/1000.0f;
    printf("%f\n",seconds);
    return(0);
    }
    else {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: XScreenSaver Extension not present\n");
    return(1);
    }
}
```

It needs a couple libraries to build. On my Fedora 19 system I needed the following libraries:

```
$ rpm -qf /lib64/libX11.so.6 /lib64/libXext.so.6 /lib64/libXss.so.1
libX11-1.6.0-1.fc19.x86_64
libXext-1.3.2-1.fc19.x86_64
libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-5.fc19.x86_64
```

Once these were installed I compiled the above like so:

```
$ gcc xidle.c -o xidle -lX11 -lXext -lXss
```

You can see that it's able to report the number of seconds that X is detecting as idle time by running it like so:

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do ./xidle ; sleep 2;done
0.005000
1.948000
3.954000
5.959000
7.965000
0.073000   <--- moved the mouse here which resets it
0.035000
```

Using this executable you could put together a script that can now know how much idle time has passed by. If it's equal to the window of time in #1 then run your first script. If that idle window is interrupted (bullet #2 from your question), then run your second script.

#### A little example

The below shows how you could construct at least the first portion of your check, if say 5 seconds passes.

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do 
  idle=$(./xidle); 
  [ $( echo "$idle > 5" | bc ) -eq 0 ] && echo "still < 5" || echo "now > 5";
  sleep 2;
done
still < 5
still < 5
still < 5
now > 5
now > 5
still < 5
still < 5
```

In the above I didn't move the mouse or hit a key for 5+ seconds. I then pressed the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and the loop switched back to `still < 5`.

#### References

- [Thread: Find out how long an X session has been idle?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1252752)